# CSS menu is being overlapped by text

Tags: html, css, menu

My css menu is being overlapped by my text at the bottom, this is causing the menu to be rendered useless as when you hover over it and initiate the drop down the text overlaps and the menu comes back up.

i would really appreciate the help with the coding. I am a absolute newbie. if there are changes to the code please could you tell me where to put them.

a link to the menu is at http://stock-trade-101.com/market-indicators/

css code

```
#cssmenu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #232323;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  width: auto;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  color: #a0a0a0;
  font-family: Verdana, 'Lucida Grande';
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  -webkit-transition: color .15s;
  -moz-transition: color .15s;
  -o-transition: color .15s;
  transition: color .15s;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -90px;
  width: 180px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s .1s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s .1s;
  -o-transition: all .3s .1s;
  transition: all .3s .1s;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 65px;
  visibility: visible;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fafafa transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul > li {
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a {
  color: #323232;
  font-family: Verdana, 'Lucida Grande';
  font-size: 13px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  padding: 5px 8px 7px 16px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.1s;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.1s;
  transition: background-color 0.1s;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -16px;
  left: 206px;
  padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  text-align: left;
  width: 180px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 190px;
  visibility: visible;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
  background-color: #cc2c24;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

HTML code for CSS menu

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Trending</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Support and Resisrance</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Creation of Support</span></a></li>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Creation of Resistance</span></a></li>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Broken Support Becoming Resistance</span></a></li>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Broken Resistance Becoming Support</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Significance of Support and Resistance</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Dow Theory</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Channel Lines</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Trendlines</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Fan Principle</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Chart Patterns</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Head And Shoulders Pattern</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Formation In Bull Market</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Formation in Bear Market</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Key Reversal</span></a></li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Symmetrical Triangles</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Ascending Triangle</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Descending Triangle</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Rectangles</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Flags</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Pennants</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub last'><a href='#'><span>Oscillators and indicators</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Leading and Lagging</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>RSI</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Stochastic Oscillator </span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>MACD</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to be working fine for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: google chrome. what browser are you using

Comment: tried with IE and chrome. Not working

Comment: Works fine with FF24, IE8, Chrome30

Comment: You guys are looking at the wrong menu - it doesn't work in Chrome.

Comment: @JoshC Sorry dude.. i was looking at top menu. my mistake. I think the issue is with transparency

Comment: it is the bottom menu. not the top menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it, the text had a `z-index` set on it, causing it to render above the menu.

Remove the following, and your problem is solved:

```
.sqs-block {
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: @user2847108 In the CSS

Comment: i cant see it in the CSS

Comment: there is none of those code line in the CSS I gave. unless i am blind

Comment: @user2847108 Go to your `site.css` line no `809`. ur blind :p